# How can I generalize this interpolation function?

Tags: function-construction

I have a data set where I want to evaluate a manual interpolation function. The part shown below expands up to the 7th power currently. I was wondering if it was possible to generalize this part of the function easily, allowing it to expand by just entering an i-number.

```
 - Exp[a (1 - x)], {a}, x]

 - Exp[a (1 - x) + b (1 - x)^2], {a, b}, x]
 - Exp[a (1 - x) + b (1 - x)^2 + c (1 - x)^3], {a, b, c}, x]
 - Exp[a (1 - x) + b (1 - x)^2 + c (1 - x)^3 + d (1 - x)^4], {a, b, c, d}, x]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, and strictly speaking it does not interpolate between given values.  Does this give what you want: `list = {a, b, c, d};
Exp[list.(x - 1)^Range@Length@list]`?

Comment: What is an `i-number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first bit of housekeeping I'll do is prevent the notebook from miniaturising super-/sub-scripts so I can see what is going on.

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ScriptSizeMultipliers -> 1]
```

Next I'll enable a new symbol $a_i$ by using the *Notations* package.

```
Needs["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["a", "_Integer"]]]
```

The `Symbolize` is easy to enter if you use the *Notation Palette* that the Notation package loads for you. Be sure not to delete the input box but put the pattern inside of it.

[image]

With $a_i$ symbolised we can now construct a function to get the expansion. It looks a lot less cryptic when it is entered in Mma.

[image]

```
f[n_Integer /; n >= 0] := 
 \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[ExponentialE]\), \(
 \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]
 \*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(i\)] 
 \*SuperscriptBox[\((1 - x)\), \(i\)]\)]\)
```

Using `f` gets the expansion needed.

[image]

```
f[7]
(*
E^((1 - x) Subscript[a, 1] + (1 - x)^2 Subscript[a, 2] + 
 (1 - x)^3 Subscript[a, 3] + (1 - x)^4 Subscript[a, 4] + 
 (1 - x)^5 Subscript[a, 5] + (1 - x)^6 Subscript[a, 6] + 
 (1 - x)^7 Subscript[a, 7])
*)
```

It can also be used with some replacement rules to get `f` for a set coefficients.

```
coeffs = {2, 3, 45.3, \[Pi], 22.456, 2, 0.44};
expand7 = f[7] /. (Subscript[a, #] -> coeffs[[#]] & /@ Range[7])
```

[image]

and to get the value for an `x`

```
expand7 /. x -> 2
(* 1.12231*10^-27 *)
```

Hope this helps.

**Update: Show how to use with `NonlinearModelFit`**

```
data = RandomReal[{0.01, 0.07}, {3, 2}];
params = Subscript[a, #] & /@ Range[7]
fm = NonlinearModelFit[data, f[7], params , x];
Normal[fm]
```

`params` is assigned the list of parameters you need for the model. `f[7]` returns he expansion needed for the model. `Normal[fm]` shows the fitted model.

Comment: I'm very much surprised at how in-depth of an answer you've provided. Thank you very much for that. One thing I'm wondering still is how to complement the function with the '{a, b, c, d}, x' part, which is needed to pass the function into a NonlinearModelFit. I've tried things like `f[n_Integer /; n >= 0] := {
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[ExponentialE]\), \(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(i\)] 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((1 - x)\), \(i\)]\)]\), Subscript[a, i], x};`

But that doesn't work, as the ai doesn't exist outside the exponent.

Comment: @user27448 I'm not certain why you are trying to change the definition of `f`. The definition I provided is the one needed to specify the model.  See the update for details.

Comment: I wanted to put everything in a single function so I wouldn't have to deal with specifying the range in two places. But this will work too!